# Dataframe becomes a numpy array after using SimpleImputer .I want it to return a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

In the below notebook , after imputing the missing values using SimpleImputer, the dataframe was converted to a numpy array, how do I make sure that it's type remains as a dataframe itself ?

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel("dummy.xlsx")
```

[image: DataFrame without imputing the values..]

```
imp = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')
df2=imp.fit_transform(df2)
df2
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always post your code as markdown and never as picture. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of [`sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.fit_transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html#sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.fit_transform) says clearly that it will return a `numpy.array`:

> **Returns**: **`X_newnumpy`: array of shape `[n_samples, n_features_new]`**
>
> Transformed array.

So you cannot "make sure that it's type remains as a dataframe". However, you can of course feed the resulting `numpy.array` in the `pandas.DataFrame()` constructor

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Mocking your data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3))
df[df > 0.9] = np.nan

imp = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')

# Feeding resulting numpy array from fit_transform directly to new df2
df2 = pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(df))
```

That's it

```
>>> type(df2)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```